# Rundeck options variable display

Tags: json, rundeck

I have create a rundeck Job with cascaded options. When I want to used this options one information is missing.

for one option a json file provide value with the below format:

```
[
{"name":"RW","value":"['IP1', 'IP2']"},
{"name":"RO","value":"['IP4', 'IP3']"},
{"name":"ROOT","value":"['IP1', 'IP2']"}
]
```

In rundeck I can select RW for example and the value of my options will be ['IP1','IP2'] but I also interested by the json name RW.
[rundeck options screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTNrX.png)

${option.PROPERTIES.value} => ['IP1','IP2']
I would like to get if possible the mysterious value:
${option.PROPERTIES.XXXXX} => RW

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way to do that is using some script that takes the name and use it later, like [this](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/psMIk7BOU4k/m/f2ijKs6TAAAJ) thread, and this GitHub [ticket](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5898#issuecomment-611817976).